Blender Geometry-nodes Math Error
i am not able to type the speed of light in a node.
299792458 is always replaced by 299792448
Even if i try to make an addition, blender is giving me 2+2=7 ...
It's literally impossible to use the correct number in a node.
How can i fix this ?


Do you know about float point accuracy and the supported numbers of significant digits? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514892/how-many-digits-can-float8-float16-float32-float64-and-float128-contain

Float/Integer overload?

Out of curiosity, what would you like to do with this number ? If it is arithmetic, not just display, I think you will have to "emulate" double-precision float using two single-precision floats.

You're probably running into a float precision error : $c$ is too great to be represented accurately using a 32-bit float number. Try inputting the speed of light as an integer instead, using the integer node.
[Wiki] General concept of single-precision floating-point
[Blender] Similar precision error for vertex coordinates
As for the "2+2=7" part, can you tell when it happens exactly? this one is more surprising.

@Thewho77 Just as Hadriscus said, you cannot have an accurate representation of 299792458 as a (32-bit) floating point number. But: it is not as simple as just using the Integer node for the input. If you want to do something like the addition or add decimals to the string, it will not work. Because the Math node will convert the integers to floats for adding them (precision is lost) and even if you plug the value directly into the Value to String node it will become 299792448 if you leave it set to Float. You will have to change the Value to String node to Integer as well.

Of course since you cannot use addition for this and you have to change the Value to String node to Integer, you don't need a separate value node as input and can enter the value directly into the Value to String node. But just as Hadriscus I would be interested to see the 2 + 2 = 7 issue... because this should not happen (at least not with the setup shown in your question).

@GordonBrinkmann there are integer math nodes in Blender 4.3 which allow you to make operations on integers without temporarily converting them to floats.

@MarkusvonBroady Oh, I didn't notice that - that's great. But still, assuming the Thewho77 would simply use his previous setup and just exchange the input value to an Integer node as suggested in this answer, it would still not work. And apart from that I do not know if for any reason the 21 decimals of the original nodetree are wanted (since they are there even though the added value has no decimals), then it would also be necessary to keep the Value to String node at Float, which brings us back to the original problem, the precision error no matter how many or few decimals are used.

@GordonBrinkmann there's no point in using the "Decimals" socket above 2²³, because at that point the float no longer stores any significant (non-zero) fraction digits.

@MarkusvonBroady I just say what I see in the question, I have no idea what the intention behind it is and I don't care. I was just trying to make the asker aware that the exact thing shown there will not be possible, even with integers as input. And it doesn't seem as if the OP is really experienced in floating point mathematics.

Geometry Nodes implement floats as IEE754 float32 with 23 bits of precision. You can read more about it here:
Float/Integer overload?
In your case you can use integers instead; Blender 4.3 provides both integer math nodes and direct integer to string conversion:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
Before Blender 4.3 you had to be very creative:
Geometry Nodes: How to Read Last Digit of a Big Integer?
But even now, Blender doesn't support "big numbers", as in, it has an inevitable limit on how big a number can be. While, as in the first link, the biggest float32 holding an integer from which you can subtract $1$ without an error is $2²⁴=16777216$, but the biggest possible float32 at all, this time limited by 8 bits of the exponent, is
$$340282346638528859811704183484516925440$$
what's the largest number float type can hold?
It's a lot, but if you want perfect precision for some reason, the integer value can hold only up to $2147483647$ which is the default maximum value of an integer socket.
This means, while you can use the integer type to store the speed of light, you can't do it to store another constant: the second-defining number of transitions between hyperfine ground-states in absolute zero temperature and outside of external influences (e.g. gravitational field) of Caessium 133 atom is exactly:
$$9,192,631,770$$
which is more than
$$2,147,483,647$$
